# magento 19:how can i upgrade 1.9.2.2 to 1.9.3.6

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to upgrade the magento version
I have now 1.9.2.2 magento version
I go to downloader and check for update
when i clicked in commit change this error shows

> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.3.6 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been resolved
I first got a backup from the site
Then I replaced the new version (magento 1.9.3.6) files with the previous version(1.9.2.2)
There is no problem right now

Answer (score 2):

By using following steps, you can upgrade from current magento version to lastest magento version.

Updating Magento via SSH can be done via the following commands:

> chmod 550 mage
>
> ./mage mage-setup .
>
> ./mage config-set preferred_state stable
>
> ./mage sync
>
> ./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community
>   Mage_All_Latest --force
>
> php shell/indexer.php reindexall
>
> rm -rf downloader/.cache/ var/cache/

Comment: I write this code and error shows


 ./mage mage-setup
Running initial setup...
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /opt/cpanel/ea-php                      56/root/etc/php.ini on line 320 in Unknown on line 0
Success
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /opt/cpanel/ea-php                      56/root/etc/php.ini on line 320 in Unknown on line 0
Success
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /opt/cpanel/ea-php                      56/root/etc/php.ini on line 320 in Unknown on line 0
Error: and ....

Comment: Yes. answer updated

Comment: please refer this link. https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/updating-magento1/

Comment: i reffer  the link and upgrade from downloader 
this error shows
CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.3.6 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2